# Encoding a Parameter List for a Hasql query

Tags: postgresql, haskell, contravariance, hasql

I'm trying to get [Hasql](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasql) to encode a list for a "select ... where in" query. It typechecks if I use `contramany` from [contravariant-extras](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-extras), but I get a syntax error at runtime.

```
import qualified Database.Encoders as E
import Contravariant.Extras

getTeamMembership :: Query [TeamId] [(TeamId, EmployeeId)]
getTeamMembership = statement q enc def True
  where
    enc = contramany (E.value E.teamId)
    q = "select workteam, employee \
        \from workteam_employee where workteam in $1"
```

Is it not possible to encode a parameter list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "IN" operator does not support that. You can only specify the individual values with it (e.g., `IN ($1, $2, $3)`). However what you want is easily achievable with the Array encoder and `any` and `all` Postgres functions, as per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20944).

There are [some Hasql tests showing it in action](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/hasql/blob/a1a5e15da828617ca25104e702c03a95e04ecfc8/tasty/Main.hs#L25-L59).

There's also been [a discussion on that subject](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/hasql/issues/61) on the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks that works! Instead of `contramany (E.value E.teamId)` I now have: `E.value (E.array (E.arrayDimension foldl' (E.arrayValue E.teamId)))`